# Update panel with databound not refreshing to the first page when a change is performed

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, panel

I have a `Listview` with a dropdownlist choice in a panel. Let said I have two pages of elements to the `Listview`.  In the dropdownlist I have `ChoiceA` and `ChoiceB`.

When I execute the first time it show up the `ChoiceA` page1.  I clicked on the NEXT button at the bottom of the list.  page2 is showing up for `ChoiceA`.  I changed to `ChoiceB`, **page2 of `ChoiceB` is showing up**.  I would expect page1 of `ChoiceB` showing up.  Am I wrong on this  or this is how it is suppose to be working?

Here is the code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indexDdl = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
    indexDdl++;
    Session["carId"] = indexDdl;
    DropDownList1.PageIndex =0;  <== this is not existing for a dropdownlist (it is for gridview)

    ListAppointement(indexDdl);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of how this is done?

Comment: @rae1 I don't see any added code sorry, can you put it back ?